# Get a value from a name value pair in a string

Tags: sql, postgresql

With the following example, what would be the best way to get the account id 123abc returned?

```
with 

pairs as (
select 'blah=foo|something=else|account_id=123abc|fruits=apples' pears
)

select [I want account_id] from pairs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses `regexp_matches()`:

```
select (regexp_matches(pears, 'account_id=([^|]+)'))[1]
from pairs
```